# Guard: batch watch notifications

Tags: ruby, guard

Is it possible to batch [guard's](https://github.com/guard/guard) `watch` notifications?

For example, if a subfolder is moved, `watch` emits an event for every file. What I actually want is one notification, not several, if something changes.

Comment: I don't think it's currently possible but it does seem like Guard should debounce these events somehow.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, folder is not file). For example you can write some code in Guardfile, which will check presence of folders,subfolder or other not .rb files and run test for them.

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't batch changes and therefore doesn't have all the benefits of doing so, if all you need to do is prevent multiple builds after several files are saved at once, you can use a debounce mechanism such as the following:

```
LAST_REBUILD = Time.now
DEBOUNCE = 2 #seconds
guard :shell do
  watch(%r{PATTERN}) do |m|
    since_last = Time.now - LAST_REBUILD
    if since_last > DEBOUNCE
      n 'Rebuilding'
      if system('LONG_RUNNING_PROCESS')
        n 'Build complete'
        LAST_REBUILD = Time.now
      end
    else
      n "Skipping rebuild after only #{since_last} seconds"
  end
end
```